# Save BottomNavigationView selected item during screen rotation

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

Using ASL's 25.0 `BottomNavigationView` i'm faced with some troubles, like a save selected item (or his index) and selected item programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are [plenty](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/bottomnavigationview-missing-pearls-eaa950f9ad4e) of features missing in `BottomNavigationView` at this stage.

Your question was really interesting and I wrote this extended `BottomNavigationView` that preserves the state and, in your case, saves last selected item.

Here is [gist to the code](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/c426abe41d98d5c2f68621c85532ea88)

This extension includes:

- Gives public two method to set and get selected items programatically.
- Saves and restores state only for the last selection.

Lets wait until ASL devs [fix this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225900&q=BottomNavigationView&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened).

Comment: Why not set the desired item as checked? like they suggest in the last link you posted (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225900&q=BottomNavigationView&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)
     
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(selectedItem).setChecked(true);

Answer (score 5):

Agree with Nikola!

I created my own [gist](https://gist.github.com/borichellow/f7dd87dc4c81419efe48d1026b561b98) too

To save state after rotation you need add to you `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("opened_fragment", bottomNavigation.getCurrentItem());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and into `onCreate` method, just after setting up `BottomNavigationView`:

```
final defaultPosition = 0;
final int bottomNavigationPosition = savedInstanceState == null ? defaultPosition :
            savedInstanceState.getInt("opened_fragment", defaultPosition);

bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(bottomNavigationPosition);
```

The biggest plus of this gist is: There are few kinds of listeners, it shows you previous selection position and listeners react even when the position is set programmatically. Everything is written in link, use if you need.

Comment: If a position is considered to be interest of the view then it must be saved inside the view implementation. Therefore, it is common practice to save it in the view's appropriate save and restore state methods, than going to `Activity` class.

Answer (score 4):

I am working with BottomNavigationView and here is the code with which the app is working correctly on screen rotation.
Firstly, I created a variable to hold the id of selected menu
`private int saveState;`
Saving the value of id by taking the selected menu id in the variable

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(saveState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        saveState = navigation.getSelectedItemId();
    }
```

Then in the onCreate method retrieving the value of id if available

```
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            navigation.setSelectedItemId(saveState);
        }else{
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, MapFragment.newInstance());
            transaction.commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and what I did was to update from **25.0.1** to **25.3.1** and it started working correctly without the need of no additional code. You can check the [Support Library Revision website](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) for the latest version.

I hope it helps.